# Postsharp : build fails with licence issue by using postsharp version 5.0.26

Tags: postsharp

I choose to use postsharp express to build caching aspects in my project, but my project doesn't build in VS2017. i get a licence issue in the error list. although i have a license on the system.

[image: Build error]

license shown in the postsharp settings 
[image: license]

Below are 2 more observations

1. Which ever project postsharp is enabled am not able to debug.(compiled images are installed for all the version that i using)
2. Build issue will be solved if i use the nuget -Version 5.0.22-preview -Pre

is there something that i have missed installing for 5.0.26 ?. can somebody help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Since PostSharp 5, it is no longer possible to use Essentials License in other location than current user registry. Please renew your license in menu PostSharp > Options > License > Register License > Use PostSharp Essentials.

I suppose that the reason why the license you show on the screenshot is not used is mentioned in the warning you have not included in the screenshot.